# TypeError: First Argument must be a string or Buffer

Tags: node.js

I originally was using node v4.4.5 and running nodemon seemed to work. As soon as I installed a newer version everything broke. I am not too sure why I am getting this error as I am just trying to get a simple node running.

Heres the Code.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
console.log('client request URL: ', request.url);
if(request.url === '/') {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', function (errors, contents){
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
        response.write(contents); 
        response.end();
    });
}
else {
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end('File not found!!!');
}
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log("Running in localhost at port 8000");
```

Comment: Can you please define at which line you get the error? One reason for this issue can be the line `response.write` because `content` is undefined. Maybe `fs.readFile` callback has received an error (errors) and you are not checking for those errors.

Comment: Agree with @MatteoRagni, the line number which causes error need to be posted. Also, it's likely to be a read-file-failure issue.

Comment: It doesn't specify. It'll run in the terminal but once I go to my localhost on the web it gets that error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on Node version : V8.2.1.
Page gets rendered without any error.
Install latest stable version of Node.js :V6.11.2

Comment: As read-file and write-response are very basic operation, it's unlikely to be a  Node.js environment issue.

Comment: It'll run in the terminal, but as soon as you open it up in the localhost, it gets that error.

Comment: Place your index.html at root level directory 
eg :-
`
    Server
         |-app.js
         |-index.html
`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the line of error it is quite difficult. The library you are using are quite basic and functionality you are employing should not differ (in terms of interface) across versions you cited.

I suggest you to check the read operation. The callback of `fs.readFile` has an `errors` field that has not been checked. If an error occurred, `contents` may remain undefined, and thus the error is raised by `response.write` method, that requires a buffer or a string as argument.

You can try:

```
response.write(String(contents));
```

and your page should show a simple "undefined" string. If that is the case, then the next step is to understand why "index.html" cannot be opened.

You may run your code line by line using node debugger:

```
node inspect script.js
```

You should insert `debugger;` where you want the line by line inspector to stop. Check the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

Comment: Thank you for the documentation. You were right, it had to do with that specific line because it was undefined. Here is what the error was giving me  though.

Comment: client request URL:  /
    _http_outgoing.js:457                                                                          
     throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');